# MySQLdb and Scrapy: INSERT INTO Error

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am trying to use the INSERT INTO command using Scrapy and MySQLdb to place the scraped data into a local MySQL database, and I have been trying to figure this one out for days, but haven't yet found a solution. I hope someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong as I am new to Python.

Here is the spider.py:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.log import *
from folketing_crawler.settings import *
from folketing_crawler.items import FolketingCrawlerItem

class FolketingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ft2'
    allowed_domains = ["ft.dk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ft.dk/Dokumenter/Vis_efter_type/Beslutningsforslag.aspx?session=&caseStatus=-1&ministerArea=-1&committee=&proposedBy=1&startDate=20110915&endDate=20140421&dateRelatedActivity=100242%2f200049&sortColumn=&sortOrder=&startRecord=&totalNumberOfRecords=&numberOfRecords=999&pageNr=#dok"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = FolketingCrawlerItem()
        item['nr'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Here is the pipelines.py:

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class FolketingCrawlerPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', passwd='password', db='ftdb', host='localhost', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        cursor = db.cursor()  
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (hire_date) VALUES (%s)", item['nr'])
        db.commit()

        print "INSERT was successful"
        return item
```

Here is the items.py:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class FolketingCrawlerItem(Item):
    nr = Field()
```

and in settings.py I have added this to call the pipeline:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'folketing_crawler.pipelines.FolketingCrawlerPipeline': 500
}
```

It seems that "cursor.execute" in pipeline.py is wrong, but I have tried every different version of it I could find online, including:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (hire_date) VALUES (%s)", item['nr'])
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO employees (hire_date) VALUES (%s)""", item['nr'])
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (hire_date) VALUES (%s)", (item['nr']))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (hire_date,) VALUES (%s,)", (item['nr'],))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (hire_date) VALUES (%s)", str(item['nr'])
```

and I have tried every combination I could, but perhaps the problem lies in the spider, where the data is stored in item['nr']? I receive the following error, when running the above scrapy project:

```
exceptions.TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Hope someone can help figure out this problem. I need to store the list of data in a row, so that each "piece" of data is on a new row in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First try your SQL directly in database. If `item['nr']` is not string then convert it to string (you can try to print it after conversion to check result). Text values in SQL need `quotation marks`

Comment: item['nr'] is supposed to be the placeholder for the scraped data, shown in the spider.py here:`item['nr'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()`, but I dont know if something is wrong in the spider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking in a scrapy shell session,

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.ft.dk/Dokumenter/Vis_efter_type/Beslutningsforslag.aspx?session=&caseStatus=-1&ministerArea=-1&committee=&proposedBy=1&startDate=20110915&endDate=20140421&dateRelatedActivity=100242%2f200049&sortColumn=&sortOrder=&startRecord=&totalNumberOfRecords=&numberOfRecords=999&pageNr=#dok"
2014-07-01 01:29:28+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
...
sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'B 2',
 u'B 3',
 u'B 4',
 u'B 5',
 u'B 6',
...
 u'B 88',
 u'B 89',
 u'B 90',
 u'B 91',
 u'B 92',
 u'B 93']

In [2]:
```

If you want to store 1 row per element in the list above, you should probably use something like:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO employees (hire_date) VALUES (%s)",
                   [(nr,) for nr in item['nr']])
```

Comment: Paul, thank you so much! that worked like a charm! Been trying for days to make it work - and now it finally does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`hire_date` looks like a SQL timestamp.  Feed it a Python `datetime` object, like so:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (hire_date) VALUES (?)", (datetime.datetime.now(),) )
```

Note: `execute` always takes a single argument, generally a tuple.  Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

Comment: And what if `item['nr']` is not `timestamp` or keeps different date than today ?

Comment: @furas thanks for the feedback.  I modified the example, and added some docs that will help.  The real issue is using "?" for placeholders, and passing a single row arg to `execute`.

Comment: But you still use `datetime.datetime.now()` but OP has `item['nr']` :)

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the replies. "hire_date" is not a timestamp. It's simply the name of a column in the mysql database set to varchar. I tried to substitute the "%s" with "?" but it gave me the exact same error:  exceptions.TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
item['nr'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()
```

return a tuple, have you tried just getting the first element.

```
item['nr'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
```